# JPA 2.1 and Hibernate with multiple MappedSuperclass

Tags: hibernate, jpa, mappedsuperclass

I dont know if this a error or a normal feature, but my MappedSuperclass properties arent reconized by JPA/hibernate after I use a multi hierarchy. I have those classes:

```
  @MappedSuperclass
  public abstract class AbstractDomain{
    private Integer userId;

    @Column
    public Integer getUserId(){
       return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Integer userId){
      this.userId=userId;
    }
  }

   public class Invoice extends AbstractDomain{
   }

  @Entity
  public class InvoiceEntity extends Invoice{

  }
```

Is that right?

Comment: Your code does not even compile  private getUser(){} has no return type. Can you please show the "real" code? Thanks.

Comment: I updated the code to something more practical, but I cant show the full code 'cause its too big and this little example display the issue well. But the problem only occuour when I going to persist an entity, to load a HQL its all good and fine.